# Equational theory for the cyclic groups

Tags: universal-algebra

Is there a finite, first-order equational theory whose models are exactly the finite cyclic groups? (An equational theory that uses $\mathbb{N}$ clearly would be 'cheating').

For example of a similar pair of question/answer, the theory of commutative monoids gives rise to (exactly) the symmetric group $S_n$. The simplest link is via Species, where free commutative monoids (on a single generator $X$) are Bags over $X$ and the Species of Bags is $\Sigma_n X^n//S_n$.

What I'm looking for is a similar story for $\Sigma_n X^n // C_n$, if it exists.

Another rephrasing: in the usual way of seeing free (term) algebras for equational theories, the theory's axioms give rise to an equivalence relation on terms. This equivalence relation can been seen as arising from a Groupoid formed by the terms are objects, term equivalences as morphisms, and transitivity as composition. $X^n // C_n$ is indeed a Groupoid, but does it arise naturally in that setting, as a 'symmetry' of an equational theory? (It is interesting to note that Monoid gives rise to the trivial group, as each Groupoid of terms is contractible).

Comment: If $\mathbf{Z}$ is a model, then so is its ultrapower (which is not cyclic).

Comment: Edited to say 'finite cyclic group'.

Comment: But still any ultraproduct of finite cyclic groups (of unbounded size w.r.t. the ultrafilter) will still be non-cyclic. Maybe you mean "whose finite models"?

Comment: Doesn't the fact that the direct produict of two cyclic groups is not necessarily cyclic prove that the answer is negative? What am I missing?

Comment: In any case there is no first-order formula at all [i.e., regardless of equational] that is true for finite cyclic groups and false for all other finite groups.

Comment: Finite cyclic groups (or even just any set of cyclic groups of unbounded sizes) generate the variety of all abelian groups.

Comment: Though, actually, that might not be the intended question. If I ignore the title and the first paragraph (to which the answer is “hell no”, as the comments demonstrate), the rest of the question seems to be about something completely different (but I can’t tell what it is as I do not know the first thing about species).

Comment: By the way (as a tangential comment on the previous comments), the first-order theory of finite cyclic groups can be easily explicitly characterized using Szmielew invariants: a structure $A$ satisfies all first-order sentences valid in all finite cyclic groups (or equivalently, it is elementarily equivalent to an ultraproduct of finite cyclic groups) if and only if it is an abelian group such that $|A[p]|\le p$ and $|A/pA|\le p$ for all primes $p$, where $A[p]=\{x\in A:px=0\}$.

Comment: That all finite cyclic groups generate the variety of abelian groups seems to be 'the' answer, i.e. no.

I have seen a relational specification for these, so I guess that's what I will have to use.